# Slow wifi connection on a laptop via android hotspot

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, hot-spot

I have a problem with wifi connection on my laptop when I'm connecting via a hotspot on my anfroid phone. I can connect successfully however the speed is extremaly slow. My operation system is kubuntu 16.04. Wifi options on the phone - wpa2 psk 2.4ghz. I'd like to notice that I don't have this problem in windows environment on the same laptop - wifi works fine. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Please check if bandwidth throttling option is on or not, inside wlan hotspot option.

Comment: Please use system monitor to see your current internet speeds. It might be possible that applications running in the background might be using a large portion of your bandwidth.

Comment: I can see in network manager that sent/received amount of data is very low (1-2kbps). Sometimes it falls to 0. For instance skype can connect to the server, but I cant download any page in my browser and thunderbird cant connect to email servers.

Comment: Could you check by USB tethering your phone and check if the same problem persists?

Comment: Could you explain what "usb tethering" is and how to check it?

Comment: This page will guide you through it. Also could you please quote @Yaksha(or anyone who should be notified) in your further comments so that i get notified of further comments from your side.http://www.junauza.com/2012/07/how-to-tether-android-smartphone-to.html?m=1

Comment: Also, have you tried your WiFi connection with any other network? Does it work as expected? If not, there's your answer: You need to troubleshoot your WiFi device in Ubuntu, the network/hotspot it's connecting to being irrelevant.